# How to change LDR output in simulator 123D Circuits?

Tags: simulator, photoresistor

I used simulator [123d.circuits.io](http://123d.circuits.io) to create simulation of basic circuit with LDR: LDR is connected to 5V and via 10K resistor to GND. Wire between LDR and resistor is connected to analog pin where I read ADC values and display them using serial monitor. This works fine. But I would like to *how to change lighting level of LDR in simulation* because this way LDR shows still the same value. I tried putting LED or light bulb near LDR but it doesn't seem to have any influence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found it myself. You can click on LDR during simulation and bar to adjust lighting appears above it.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: It is complete answer to the question.